# Need to create a workflow to send an email before the Item approch 1 item

Tags: designer-workflow

i have  created a list on a SharePoint and in the list i have a column for quantity. i need to receive  an email once the quantity  approach 1 item  .

if you can help me to create a workflow for the quantity column which enable me to alert me with  an email before the quantity approache number 1

your help if highly appreciate

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a SP 2010 workflow on that list and configure it to start "When an item is created"
2. Add the action "If any value equals any value".
3. Click on the link of first "any value" and click on Add/Update data thhen provide the Data source: i.e. list you're working with. 
   Select the Field "quantity" // quantity column in the list. Click on OK
4. Click on the second link of "any value" and type 1.
5. Click on send an email action.
6. Provide the "To" users, subject of email and body of email >> mandatory
7. Save and Publish the worklfow.

Comment: Thanks for the help . a found a solution .  here is the workflow which i have done  ....   if the value is equal or less 1 than send an email  .  it worked perfectly .